# Is there any valid complex or just real solution to $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)} = 2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Solve for all complex $x$ such that $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)} = 2$ using Lambert W function .

I'd just encountered the question in the series after that of $$\sin(x)^{\sin(x)} = 2$$ where Lambert W function was used giving some complex solutions of $x$ and was wondering if there were any similar way to solve the above problem.

**What I've found:**

[image]

Can it be proved ?

My attempt :

[image]

Comment: Can you be specific on $x$, whether real, complex, etc.

Comment: @TymaGaidash yeah it's taken from there

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi complex

Comment: @TymaGaidash nope the equation will actually invert into $\sqrt{1-y}^\sqrt{y} = 2$ where $\sqrt{y} = \cos(x)$

Comment: @TymaGaidash but how to solve it exactly?

Comment: @TymaGaidash can u please do that ?

Comment: I see no reason to suppose there is a solution using the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex solutions always diverge, from what was tried, using
[Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem), but the real solutions are:
$$\begin{align}\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}=2\mathop \iff^{x=\cos^{-1}(-\sqrt y)}y=1-4^{-\frac1{\sqrt y}}\implies x_k=\left(2k+\frac12\right)\pi+\sin^{-1}\left(1+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left.\frac{4^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt w}}}{\sqrt w}\right|_1\right),k\in\Bbb Z\end{align}$$

Expand $e^y$ as a series using [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorial+power):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left.\frac{4^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt w}}}{\sqrt w}\right|_1= \frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left.\frac{e^{-\ln(4)nw^{-\frac12}}}{\sqrt w}\right|_1=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(-\frac m2-\frac12\right)^{(n-1)}\frac{(-\ln(4)n)^m}{m!}$$

which expressible through the [confluent Fox Wright function $_1\Psi_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) and [Fox H](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left.\frac{4^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt w}}}{\sqrt w}\right|_1=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12-\frac m2\right)(-\ln(4)n)^m}{\Gamma\left(\frac32-n-\frac m2\right)m!}=\,_1\Psi_1\left(^{\left(\frac12,-\frac12\right)}_{\left(\frac32-n,-\frac12\right)};-\ln(4)n\right)$$

The $m,n$ sums are interchangeable. Also, @Mariusz Iwaniuk reduced $_1\Psi_1$ into $_1\text F_2$ functions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889043/reduce-fracdn-1dwn-1-frac4-n-sqrt-w-sqrt-w-big-1-frac1). Therefore:

$$\bbox[border:2px dashed blue]{\begin{align}\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}=2\implies x_k= \left(2k+\frac12\right)\pi+\sin^{-1}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{\frac12}n\,_1\text F_2\left(n-\frac12;\frac12,\frac12;(\ln(2)n)^2\right)+\ln(2)\,_1\text F_2\left(n;1,\frac32;(\ln(2)n)^2\right)\right),k\in\Bbb Z\end{align}}$$

shown here:

[image]

Comment: sure if u can solve it for real roots

Comment: An integral representation like [for FoxH](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html) or maybe one for $_1\Psi_1$ could give an integral representation of the real roots.

Comment: thanks a lot but i was wondering can't it have any simpler solution 

Comment: Can you explain how from: $$y=1-4^{-\frac1{\sqrt y}}$$ to: $$x_n=\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi+\sin^{-1}\left(1+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left.\frac{4^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt w}}}{\sqrt w}\right|_1\right)$$ step by step using  Lagrange reversion ? Thanks

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  You can use $x=a+bf(x)\implies g(x)=g(a)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{da^n}[g’(a)f(a)^n]$. Now set $a=1,b=-1,f(y)=4^{-\frac1{\sqrt y}},g(a)=\sqrt a$ $y=1-4^{-\frac1{\sqrt y}}\implies \sqrt y=1+\frac12\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{da^{n-1}}\left.\frac{4^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt a}}}{\sqrt a}\right|_{a=1}$. Finally, use $\cos^{-1}(-x)=\frac\pi2+\sin^{-1}(x)$ and $2\pi k$ for all solutions.

Comment: Confluent **Fox Wright function**  can by simplified to: `(Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2) + n}, {1/2, 1/2}, n^2 Log[2]^2])/
 Gamma[3/2 - n] + (-1)^
  n Gamma[1 + n]  HypergeometricPFQ[{n}, {1, 3/2}, n^2 Log[2]^2]  Log[
   4]`. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk How did you simplify it? Maybe you converted to FoxH and used a command like [this](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FoxHToMeijerG/). Summing over $m$ in Mathematica does not evaluate.

Comment: Yes,I converted to FoxH and then to MeijerG. On Maple I converted MeijerG to hypergeometric function.I tried simplify more, but I failed :)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Certain Meijer G forms may only be reduced by Maple, but it is an additional software to use. If you know another way to simplify it, please the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889043/reduce-fracdn-1dwn-1-frac4-n-sqrt-w-sqrt-w-big-1-frac1) if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Graphing, you more than likely saw that the first positive zero of function
$$f(x)=\sin(x)^{\cos(x)} - 2$$ is, say, smaller than $\pi$.

Let $x=\pi-t$ and look for the zero of function
$$g(t)= \sin(t)^{-\cos(t)} - 2$$ Using a Laurent series around $t=0$
$$g(t)=-2+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{6} t \,(3 \log (t)+1)+O\left(t^3\right) \tag 1$$

So the very first estimate is $t_0=\frac 12$. Make one iteration of Newton method for $(1)$ to obtain
$$t_1=\frac 12-\frac{3 \log (2)-1}{40+6 \log (2)}=0.475556\quad \implies \quad x_1=2.66604$$ while the "exact" solution is $x=2.66536$.