# How do I solve the following equation exactly: $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}=2$?

Tags: lambert-w

I solved the following equation yesterday for fun and I have the exact result (But these are just some solutions, not all):
$$\sin(x)^{\sin(x)}=2 \iff x=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln (\exp^{W(\ln(2))}\pm{\sqrt{\exp^{2W(\ln(2))}-1}}) +2k\pi,$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function.

But how can I solve $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}=2$ now?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Is there any valid complex or just real solution to $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)} = 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692173/is-there-any-valid-complex-or-just-real-solution-to-sinx-cosx-2) [What is the value of $x$ such that: ${(\sin x)}^{\cos x} = \frac{1}{2}$ , considering $0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739051/)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152275/discussion-on-question-by-mordor-07-how-do-i-solve-the-following-equation-exactl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.